# how refraction takes place at atomic level?

Tags: photons

when light beam is incidented at some angle on the surface of a medium some part of the light is reflected and some refracted. I want to know about refraction. As the photons interact with the atom and get reemitted in all the directions, how the photons know to a particular angle they should refract?